# How to handle onChange when creating reusable components in react js

Tags: reactjs

*I have created a reusable component MobileInput. And the below code is being used inorder to use it into another component*

`MobileInput name={‘mobileInput’} Label={‘phn’} onChange={handleMobileInput}`

*I am confused like the onchange function which is handleMobileInput needs to declared in the page wherein this MobileInput reusable ftn is getting called. Or in MobileInput reusable component itself *

Comment: `I am confused like the onchange function.......reusable component itself` Didn't get  this. If you are referring to the usage of `onChange` inside MobileInput component, You can directly call it via props, no need to reinitialize

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will create this function "handleMobileInput" in which screen you are call you component and then pass it in props

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help